# cannot resize c++ std::vector that's a member variable of a class

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, stdvector, std

code (simplified version)

(part of) the class definition:

```cpp
struct foo {
    std::vector<int> data;
    foo(int a=0):data(a+1,0) {}
    void resize(int a) {
        data.resize(a+1,0);
    }
}
```

The `a+1` part is because I want the `data` to be 1-indexed to simplify some operations.

in global scope:

```cpp
int k;
foo bar;
```

in `main` function:

```cpp
std::cin>>k;
bar.resize(k);
```

Later in the `main` function, there is a call to another member function (in `foo`) that accesses the `data`, causing a `segmentation fault` (`segsegv`).

After debugging, I found that `data.size()` returns 0. Which is very unexpected.

After a very long session of debugging, I feel very confident that the problem is with the `resize`ing, which shouldn't cause any problems (it's from the standard library, after all!).

P.S. Don't accuse me for putting anything in global scope or giving public access to class members. I'm not writing any "real" program, because I'm just practicing for a programming competition.

Comment: If I wanted a 1-indexed vector I would write a function to do it rather than a class. Just some advice.

Comment: Also, are you sure `k` has the correct value you want?

Comment: And also you should use `unsigned int` instead of `int` when passing argument representing index of you vector.

Comment: @Pubby This is just a portion of the class, there are more stuff going in the class. However, debugging pinpointed this portion of the code to be the source of the bug.

Comment: Can you provide a similarly small, compilable code sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: `I feel very confident that the problem is with the resizeing` It's not.

Comment: @TheemathasChirananthavat That's not how it works. UB in one part of your code can manifest symptoms in a _completely_ different part of your code! e.g. if this object is accidentally overwritten elsewhere.

Comment: `I want the data to be 1-indexed to simplify some operations` This is going to be _extremely_ confusing in your code. Please reconsider.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 1. I don't know what is UB 2. I realized that the problem is actually with the debugger (see the edit) 3. 1-based arrays are useful when writing certain data structures such as heaps and fenwick trees

Comment: @TheemathasChirananthavat: 1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior; 2. No, it's not. It's a problem with your code; 3. Not really.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm upvoting your comment because it was a push that made me found the problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 1. OK 2. a bug in the debugger makes debugging a lot harder (I always rely on the debugger) 3. I think it might be about personal opinion (1-based and 0-based simplify different parts of code) BTW the class isn't too big for me to manage the confusion (around 40 lines)

Comment: Arrays are _universally_ 0-indexed in computing. Even VB eventually figured this out. Changing this (_especially_ if you do it in one part of your code, but not the other) is _incredibly_ confusing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think this argument should end now, it depends on personal opinion as long as it is a small program (I'm just practicing for a competition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> After a very long session of debugging, I feel very confident that the problem is with the `resize`

It is almost certain that:

1. The issue doesn't have anything to do with `resize()`.
2. You have a memory-related bug somewhere (double delete, uninitialized/dangling pointer, buffer overrun etc).

The thing with memory-related bugs is that they can be completely symptomless until well after the buggy code has done the damage.

My recommendation would be to run your program under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) (or at least show us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that doesn't work for you).

Comment: actually, I found a bug in the debugger, edited the question (please read the edit if you have any further questions). I'm accepting your answer because you're correct that it's not related to resize at all.

Comment: @TheemathasChirananthavat If you have a different problem, sit with it for a while, think, test, reduce, etc. If you can't fix it, post a new question, don't modify this one.

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

struct foo {
  std::vector<int> data;
  explicit foo(int a=0) : data(a+1, 0) {}
  void resize(int a) {
    data.resize(a+1, 0);
  }
};

int main() {
  foo test_foo(1);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    int a = std::rand() % 65536;
    test_foo.resize(a);
    if (test_foo.data.size() != a + 1)
      return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: seems like there's a bug is in the debugger (see my edit on the question)